# My counter stops working when people change tabs

Tags: php, javascript, counter

I'm creating a browser game about soccer, and it has a counter. Everytime the counter reachs 0 (from 10 minutes) you can kick and score a goal. What happens is that if you change tabs OR stay too long in the same page (without refreshing or going to other pages of the site) the counter will freeze/stops. If you come back from the other tabs (back to the game tab) the counter will unfreeze (but it gets bugged, and it continues from a "wrong time", a time that was paused while you weren't in the game tab).

Basically that is it. What I want is for the counter to work even while you're browsing another tab (or if you don't refresh the page).

My code is the following:

```
<?php

ob_start();


$Atempo_permitido = 600; // tempo em segundos até redirecionar


$Atempo_atual = mktime(date("H:i:s"));
if($_COOKIE['ACookie_countdown']=="") {
$Atempo_entrada = mktime(date("H:i:s"));
$Atempo_cookie = '3600'; // em segundos
setcookie("ACookie_countdown", "$Atempo_entrada", time()+86400*365);
} else {
$Atempo_gravado = $_COOKIE['ACookie_countdown'];
$Atempo_gerado = $Atempo_atual-$Atempo_gravado;
$Afim = $Atempo_permitido-$Atempo_gerado;
if($Afim <= 0) {
echo "tempo esgotado";
} else {
//echo $fim;
}
}
?>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
var Asegs = '<?php if($Afim=="") { echo $Atempo_permitido+1; } else { echo "$Afim";    }     ?>';
var Ats = Asegs*10;
Atuw1();
function Atuw1(){
Asegs = parseInt(Ats / 10);
Asegs = Asegs % 3600;
Aminutes = parseInt(Asegs / 60);
Asegs = Asegs % 60;
if(Ats>0){
document.getElementById("Avalor").innerHTML = "Tempo restante: " + "00" + ":<?php         if($Afim <=540){echo "0";}?>" + Aminutes + ":" + Asegs + "h";
Ats = Ats-1;
setTimeout("Atuw1()", 100)
} else {
document.getElementById("Adiv1").innerHTML = 'Você já pode chutar!';
location.href='index.php?menu=gol';
}
}
</script>
<!-- BLOCO 1 //-->
<body onLoad="Atuw1();Btuw1();Ctuw1();Dtuw1();Etuw1();">
<div id="Avalor"></div>
<div id="Adiv1"></div>
```

If you guys could show me some light on how to make this work.

Comment: Have you tried this on all possible browsers? It could be browser specific

Comment: Yes, I tried FF, Chrome and IE.

Comment: you might want to add onunload/beforeunload = function to set cookie, but that might not work on all browsers.

Comment: Hi Class, I couldn't get this function to work properly. Could you elaborate? Also it doesn't work in chrome which is a big problem (for a game). Right down I set the page to refresh itself every 30 seconds, but I don't like this 'fix', and the players might not like too